# angularjs filter an array with string values as integers in contoller

Tags: arrays, angularjs, filter

I'm using AngularJS filter to filter an array of objects inside a controller. These objects all have a quality that is a string. I want to be able to filter the array from largest to smallest. But I can't get it filter on value of the integer inside the string.

```
array = [{
  object1 {
    value = "3"
  }, {
 object2 {
    value = "1"
  }, {
  object3 {
    value = "22"
  }]

 $filter('orderBy')( array, 'value', true );
```

This would order the array as: object2, object3, object1. I've tried using parseInt but that doesn't work. Does anyone know the correct syntax?

Comment: This more a question of how to order a array of objects in javascript rather than a angularjs specific problem. Maybe you take a look at this [example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1129216/sort-array-of-objects-by-string-property-value-in-javascript) It may could solve your problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replace `value` with a function that returns the length of the string:

```
$filter('orderBy')( array, function(item) { return parseInt( item.value ); } , true );
```

Comment: Almost correct, it turns out to be: { return parseInt( item.value );  }. I'll mark your answer as correct but you might wanna edit your post. Thanks alot though.

Comment: Edited! I think the original answer was just a reflection of what I'm doing at work :)